# Transform coordinates Seaborn/Matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

How can I transform coordinates of the plot, where 0,0 is the bottom left, and 1,1 is the top right, to the coordinate of the X and Y values shown on the graph below?

What I want to achieve is to draw the labels A, V, U, I, and M at the top of the graph, approximately at the height of where the label "Additional Information" is, but keep the X position. It will vary how many points are in the regression plot so it cannot be hard coded.

I tried to use the transData and transAxes which is described here https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html, but I could not transform to the way which here would convert the Y coordinate 0.8 to approximately 26.

Transforming the other way around would also work, but it would then need to be the X coordinate that is transformed, i.e. from 2.5 to 0.2.
[image]

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

status = ['A', 'V', 'U', 'I', 'M']
x_array = np.array([2, 4, 6, 8, 10])
y_array = np.array([5, 9, 15, 21, 27])
x, y = pd.Series(x_array, name="Values X"), pd.Series(y_array, name="Values Y")
ax_regplot = sns.regplot(x=x, y=y, scatter=True)
ax_regplot.set_title("My plot")
ax_regplot.figure.text(0.2, 0.8, "Additional Information", fontsize=8)

for i in range(len(x_array)):
    x_coordinate = x_array[i]
    y_coordinate = y_array[i]
    ax_regplot.text(x_coordinate, y_coordinate, status[i])

ax_regplot.figure.savefig("my_plot.png")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indeed work in several coordinate systems here. The idea is that the y coordinate of your text elements is in axes units (ranging from 0 to 1 over the area of the axes), and the x coordinates are in data units. For example the letter "A" is to be set at `(2, 0.8)` with 2 being data units, and 0.8 axes units. Such system is called "blended coordinate system".  We could manually create such blended systems, or use the xaxis transform, which uses this exact system anyways.

Using `annotate` instead of `text` in addition allows to add small offsets in points to the texts. This may be used to give both, the header text and the letters the same axis coordinate, but still shift them by some points relative to each other.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

status = ['A', 'V', 'U', 'I', 'M']
x = np.array([2, 4, 6, 8, 10])
y = np.array([5, 9, 15, 21, 27])


ax = sns.regplot(x=x, y=y, scatter=True)
ax.set_title("My plot")


ax.annotate("Additional Information", xy=(0,0.8), xytext=(20, 10),
                   xycoords="axes fraction", textcoords="offset points",
                   fontsize=8)

for i in range(len(x)):
    ax.annotate(status[i], xy=(x[i], 0.8), xytext=(0, -2),
                   xycoords=ax.get_xaxis_transform(), textcoords="offset points",
                   fontsize=10, ha="center")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can simply get the maximum value of `Y` using `get_ylim()` and scale it of as much as you want (in the example below I take 0.8 of the max value).
`get_ylim()` returns a tuple with the lower and upper bound of the axis, we select the upper by indexing `[1]`.

```
status = ['A', 'V', 'U', 'I', 'M']
x_array = np.array([2, 4, 6, 8, 10])
y_array = np.array([5, 9, 15, 21, 27])
x, y = pd.Series(x_array, name="Values X"), pd.Series(y_array, name="Values Y")
ax_regplot = sns.regplot(x=x, y=y, scatter=True)
ax_regplot.set_title("My plot")
ax_regplot.figure.text(0.2, 0.8, "Additional Information", fontsize=8)
```

We just need to change the last line in your loop:

```
for i in range(len(x_array)):
    x_coordinate = x_array[i]
    y_coordinate = y_array[i]
    ax_regplot.text(x_coordinate, 0.8*ax_regplot.get_ylim()[1], status[i])
```

EDIT:

Following @Rob's comment, you can generalize the answer to:

```
ylim=ax_regplot.get_ylim()
for i in range(len(x_array)):
    x_coordinate = x_array[i]
    y_coordinate = y_array[i]
    ax_regplot.text(x_coordinate, ylim[0] + .8 * (ylim[1] - ylim[0]), status[i])
```

[image: example]

Comment: you could just write the line you changed (`ax_regplot.text(x_coordinate, 0.8*ax_regplot.get_ylim()[1], status[i])`), to make it more easily visible

Comment: This assumes that the plot starts more-or-less at zero. To be more precise, use `ylim=ax_regplot.get_ylim()` and `ax_regplot.text(x_coordinate, ylim[0] + .8 * (ylim[1] - ylim[0]), status[i])`

Comment: @Rob Well, that will only matter if OP wants the text close to the lower limit but in that case I would probably scale up the lower bound `1.1*ax_regplot.get_ylim()[0]`

Comment: No, it matters when you have a compressed scale, for example if the range is 90-100. Then the original code will put the text outside of the range. With my suggestion, it will always be at 80% of the visible range.